# hex to decimal conversion error/ missing step?

Tags: binary

I'm trying to convert hex 8B to decimal.
Though I keep getting wrong decimal?
I used this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_kA5KQxByc as a guide.

I see that the soln is 139.

8B

8421 | 8421

1000 | 1011

128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1

1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1

Adding, I get 141??

Comment: $8B = 8 * 16^1 + B * 16^0$

Comment: $128+8+\color{red}{2}+1=139$... so I'm not sure where you're getting $141$ from.  $141=128+8+\color{red}{4}+1$, so maybe you misread a $2$ as a $4$.

Comment: Perhaps your error comes from your inability to read your chart you made for yourself... properly aligning things might help:  $\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}128&64&32&16&8&4&2&1\\1&0&0&0&1&0&1&1\end{array}$